# Nav buttons floating over review dialog box

Tags: bug, design, review

I was in the LQP review queue this morning and clicked the 'recommend deletion' dialog box. I dragged the dialog box away to look again at the question and noticed this:

[image: wat]

The nav buttons are floating above the review dialog!

So far I've only seen this in the LQP review queue. The dialog boxes on other pages, and even in some of the other queues, seem okay (but I don't have access to all queues).

Comment: what browser / OS are you using?

Comment: @gnat Chrome Canary / Windows. I'm trying to confirm on other browsers, but so far I haven't a review item or audit to come up to test it on.

Comment: @gnat Well I just got an audit, but clicking the 'recommend deletion' button made me pass the audit without even bringing up the dialog. Looks like it's going to be hard to reproduce.

Comment: I can confirm in the low quality queue on FF 29.0.1 (win7)

Comment: checking the style it appears the `#delete-question-popup{z-index: 10 !important}` is not large enough to surpass the auto z-index of the buttons (and it overwrites the 200 of `.popup`)